# Failed to prepare device for development Xcode (iPad, iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, simulator

Device connected to Xcode and showing error :

> This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.

I tried to connect device to Xcode using cable, and its showing error.
Also, in Xcode -> Window > device & simulator > device , showing error with warning Sign on iPad
XCODE - 14.2
iOS - 16.4.1

Answer (score 12):

1. Navigate to

> Applications > Xcode.app > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport

2. Check the folder of same iOS version of your device's.
3. If the directory is missing download support files of your iOS version from: https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases
4. Add that to DeviceSupport.
5. Clean Xcode
6. Unplug and reconnect device

Comment: I also restarted Xcode and my iPhone. Worked fine after that. I was fearing a long wait for Apple to help out. Saved my bacon! I have a 2021 MacBook M1 running Ventura 13.3.1 targeting XSMax running 16.4.1. Thanks bunches!!

Comment: where do i get the device support files?

Comment: for any one looking, i got the files from here https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport, thanks a lot guys

Comment: to get Device Support, go to Applications > Xcode.app > Right-click the Xcode version and choose Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport
Refer : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj8nvqz_57_AhWLxDgGHVMnA6sQFnoECAsQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cocoacasts.com%2Fxcode-fundamentals-could-not-locate-device-support-files%23%3A~%3Atext%3DNavigate%2520to%2520Contents%2520%253E%2520Developer%2520%253E%2520Platforms%2Cfor%2520the%2520versions%2520Xcode%2520supports.&usg=AOvVaw2A_o8CYf0YcOQJbnNa6PDZ

Comment: Thanks!! I've been restarting and starting my Iphone(s)/ Mac/swithcing ports like crazy! Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.5 on xR and iphone 13

Comment: Weird, but this did not help me. Xcode 14.2 + iOS 16.5...

Answer (score 1):

When you have this kind of problem it means that device version is not supported by xCode version. While the other answer works, there is another way without having to copy the folder.
Install the new XCode version somewhere on your Mac. Start it, connect your device, wait it is ready (check in organiser/devices). Then stop xCode.
Now you can use your older xCode : the different versions of xCide share the same directory for the supported iOS versions.