# VS Code Maui will not debug on iPad

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio-code

I’m using VS Code on a MacBook to develop iOS apps using the Maui extension.

I have Xcode 15.0.1 installed and I’m able to debug on my connected iPad (10th gen) running iOS 17.0.3 without issue.

However, when attempting to debug on the same device in VS Code I receive the following error:

Failed to mount developer tools on ‘iPad’
Could not mount developer tools on ‘iPad’: Could not locate device support files
You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it

The app is installed to the device and I am indeed able to open it manually by tapping on it, but I can’t debug the code.

Also, the app runs fine on the iPad simulator, which is 10th gen and on iOS 17.0.1

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Can [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76152010/18359438) help? You can find 
iOSDeviceSupport file in [this page](https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport).